# How to trigger a C++ application after authentication is successful in the browser?

Tags: c++, node.js, rest

I have an application running in C++ and a server in nodeJS. On the server side, I have all the authentication routes, using passport and integrated with some providers like: Google, GitHub, etc. Here's a snippet of the authentication and callback routes for GitHub authentication:

```
...
application.get('/login/github', passport.authenticate('github'), () => {})

application.get('/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: path.join(__dirname, '../views/failure.html') }), (req, res, next) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/success.html'));
        })
...
```

On the client side (C++ application), I implemented some buttons to select these providers, and depending on the selected button, the application opens the browser and passes the path of my API that performs the authentication according to the selected provider.

**Problem**: The authentication response is an HTML structure, usually provided by the provider itself. As it is not in the plans to render the HTML on the screen of the C++ application, I implemented a way for C++ to open an external browser, here is the code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
static int platform = 1;
#elif _WIN64
static int platform= 1;
#elif __linux__
static int platform = 2;
#elif __APPLE__
static int platform = 3;
#else
static int platform = 0;
#endif

...

void UserService::openPlatform(const std::string& url)
{
    std::string str;
    switch (platform) {
        case 1:
            str = "explorer";
            break;
        case 2:
            str = "xdg-open";
            break;
        case 3:
            str = "open";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Should never happen on the 3 defined platforms" << std::endl;
    }
    str.append(" " + url);
    std::system(str.data());
}

...
```

Once the authentication is successful, the callback that the provider returns is restricted to the browser (obviously) and my C++ application doesn't know what happened with the authentication. How can I trigger some feedback to my C++ application, so that it can know if the login was successful or not?

ATTEMPT 1: I've tried several ways to create custom URL schemes, but since my C++ application is cross-platform and I'm on a macOS computer, the efforts went nowhere.

ATTEMPT 2: I tried to establish a communication via websocket, although I was successful with the communication, I don't know very well how to build this authentication relationship between each client and the server.

What am I missing?

I would like the C++ application to be able to somehow know who authenticated, and if authentication was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of searching, I found a plausible solution. When the C++ application calls the authentication process in an external browser. The C++ application instances a local server, and waits for the callback to redirect to the local server. When the C++ application's local server receives the authentication result (which in this case is a UserId and an access token, or null), it shuts down the local server. I created the local server, following this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1007262/A-minimal-http-web-server-using-boost-asio).